# Error while trying to reference a hashset using Directory.EnumerateFiles in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to filter results using Directory.Enumerate in c# but I am getting the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet' to 'string'

I think I understand why as `Directory.Enumerate` already creates a string array but I am not sure what the correct way to fix this is.

Here is my code:

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string> { ".txt", ".doc", ".log" };

var fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory, "*.*")
                           .Where(f => !new FileInfo(f).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System) && 
                                       f.Contains(Path.GetExtension(extensions)));
```

Comment: `Path.GetExtension` expects a string parameter, and you are passing it a HashSet object. There should be no confusion about that error.

Comment: My understanding was that a HashSet<string> was the correct way to pass in an array of strings to c#. What should I use instead to hold the list of strings?

Comment: _"HashSet<string> was the correct way to pass in an array of strings"_ -- no, the correct way to pass an array of string is to pass an array of strings. A `HashSet<string>` is a completely different thing. But beyond that, the goal _"pass in an array of strings"_ is irrelevant to the `Path.GetExtension()` method. It expects a _single_ `string` instance. It won't accept an array or a hash set or anything else that's not a `string`.

Comment: @Confuz you just had it backwards. The path extension doesn't contain the list, the list may contain a path extension.

Comment: Thanks @insane_developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this bit is wrong:

```
f.Contains(Path.GetExtension(extensions))
```

f is a string, not the hashset, try:

```
extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f))
```

Comment: Thanks @Neil, I did have it the wrong way round. Works perfectly